# No way to make aliases work

Tags: alias

None of my aliases work. I tried the most simple thing, defining an alias to access the `Desktop/` folder from `$HOME`:

```
# just to show that I do have a Desktop/ folder
~ bf$ cd Desktop/

Desktop bf$ cd ~

~ bf$ alias dd='Desktop/'

~ bf$ cd dd
-bash: cd: dd: No such file or directory

~ bf$ echo dd
dd
```

I also tried to save this alias in .bash_profile (in my `$HOME` directory), source it, but it won't work. What's happening? Also why does echoing the alias just return its name?

Comment: `dd` is not a great choice for an alias...

Answer (score 0):

That's not how aliases work. You probably want to use an environment variable, e.g.:

```
user@host:~$ export dd='Desktop/'
user@host:~$ cd $dd
user@host:~/Desktop$
```

Or, to use an alias:

```
user@host:~$ alias dd="cd ~/Desktop"
user@host:~$ dd
user@host:~/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 0):

`Desktop/` is not a valid shell command. `cd ~/Desktop` is valid.
So...

```
$ alias dd="cd ~/Desktop"
```